# Changing Doubles To Ints

Tags: java, casting, int, double

Im working on a homework assignment for my intro to computer science class and we are are inputting basic commands to get the percentage of people who drink a certain kind of energy drink. We used JOptionPane to make text boxes and you can input the amount of people and the computer has a set percentage to get the output. My problem is i set up my variables as doubles and my answers are very long decimals. I want to convert the answers to Ints so i can get whole numbers. I have tried to do this through casting but i keep getting the error message"                              EnergyDrink.java:14: error: variable citrusEnergyDrinkers might not have been initialized". What can i do?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Please post your code sounds like it's not a casting problem but an I initialization issue to me

Comment: import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EnergyDrink
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String amountOfPeople;
double amountOfPeopleFinal;
double percentageWhoPurchaseEnergyDrinks= .14;
double PercentageWhoPreferCitrusDrink= .64;
double energyDrinkers;
double citrusEnergyDrinkers;
int energyDrinkersFinal = (int) energyDrinkers;
int citrusEnergyDrinkersFinal = (int) citrusEnergyDrinkers;

amountOfPeople= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many people were surveyed?");
amountOfPeopleFinal= Double.parseDouble(amountOfPeople);

Comment: energyDrinkers= amountOfPeopleFinal* percentageWhoPurchaseEnergyDrinks;
citrusEnergyDrinkers= energyDrinkers* PercentageWhoPreferCitrusDrink;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number of people who will buy an energy drink is"+ energyDrinkers+ "and the number who will buy citrus drinks is"+ citrusEnergyDrinkers);
}
}

Answer (score 0):

This can't be solved without code. The error is not due to any problem with the conversion, but simply as the compiler-error says:

> variable citrusEnergyDrinkers might not have been initialized

This means that the variable might not hold a value at the time you attempt to convert it, which results in undefined behaviour, which java-designers didn't allow for a reason.
The problem is as the error-message tells: `citrusEnergyDrinkers` gets its value inside some try-catch-block or a block that is only run under certain conditions, like `if`. One way to work around this would be to simply initialize `citrusEnergyDrinkers` as 0:
`double citrusEnergyDrinkers = 0;`.
Note though that this might produce incorrect results depending upon what happens when the value isn't set in case the above mentioned block of code isn't entered/breaks off before setting a value.

For the conversion:
`Math.round(citrusEnergyDrinkers)` is most likely preferable to a simple cast to `int`, since `double` most of the time has some imprecision due to the way it's stored in memory and `round` will actually round the value, while a cast will simply remove the frictional part. For example:

```
(int) 0.75 //produces 0
Math.round(0.75) //produces 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply the double by 100 and then cast to an int:

```
double d = .77583495;
int perc = (int) Math.round( d );
```

I prefer to not cast like that, but it works.

Good luck.